# Ruby send method with rails associations

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, send, dynamic-method

I have been messing about with making a sortable table module thing.  I know some might exist but want to get experience doing this myself.  I had the idea of have it like so:

```
SortedTable.new(ModelName, Hash_Of_Columns_And_Fields, ID)
```

example

```
SortedTable.new(Post, {"Title" => "title", "Body" => "body", "Last Comment" => "comment.last.title"}, params[:id])
```

I am planning to do something like:

```
def initialize(model, fields, id)
  data = {}
  model = model.capitalize.constantize
  model.find(id)
  fields.each do |column, field|
    data[column] = model.send(field)
  end
end
```

This works fine for title and body but when it comes to getting the `Last Comment` with `comment.last.title` it errors out.  I have tried doing `Post.send("comments.last.title")` but says `NoMethodError: undefined method 'comments.last.title' for #<Post:0x0000010331d220>`

I know I can do `Post.send("comments").send("last").send("title")` and that works but I can not think of how to do that dynamically by taking the fields and spliting the on . then chaining the sends.  Can anyone give me advice on how to do this?  If I am doing this completely wrong also then please say or point me in the direction of code that does something similar.  I am not a expert ruby developer but I am trying.

P.S The above code might not work as I am not at a computer with ruby/rails to test, but hopefully you get the concept.

Cheers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

first and dirtiest solution is `eval`

```
fields.each do |column, field|
  data[column] = eval("#{model}.#{field}")
end
```

next solution little more functional

```
fields.each do |column, field|
  data[column] = field.split(".").inject(model){|obj, met| obj.send(met)}
end
```

**PS**

And your design is ugly

**EDIT**

The inject can be written more concisely as `field.split('.').inject(model, :send)`. And I'd strongly discourage the `eval` way — unnecessary `evals` are one more case where you can slip up and allow arbitrary code execution, and they're also slow. (Also, I'm pretty sure that should just be `eval("model.#{field}")` — you don't want to interpolate the string value of `model`. Yet another example of how easy it is to slip up an `eval` expression.) – @Chuck

Comment: Hey,  thanks for the quick reply.  I thought my approach was going to be ugly :) Still learning.  Any advice would be appreciated.  Thanks for those solutions however!

Comment: The inject can be written more concisely as `field.split('.').inject(model, :send)`. And I'd strongly discourage the `eval` way — unnecessary `evals` are one more case where you can slip up and allow arbitrary code execution, and they're also slow. (Also, I'm pretty sure that should just be `eval("model.#{field}")` — you don't want to interpolate the string value of `model`. Yet another example of how easy it is to slip up an `eval` expression.)