# Dynamic Method Calls on Rails Association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Given an array like this:

```
%w{ field_one, field_two, some_association.field_one }
```

I need to iterate over this and dynamically call these methods on a given object, exactly as described here: [Ruby send method with rails associations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7393812/ruby-send-method-with-rails-associations)

So far I have this, which does fetch the values correctly:

```
field.include?('.') ? field.split('.').inject(some_object, :send) : some_object.send(field)
```

Additionally though, I need to call :human_attribute_name on the correct class to generate labels. What is a clean way to accomplish this?

Comment: Since what you have is working can you clarify what you mean by "Additionally though, I need to call :human_attribute_name on the correct class to generate labels." I don't know what the "correct" class is or what you mean by "labels" please explain the issue you are facing not the problem you have already solved.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what you're trying to accomplish but if I had to guess I'd say you're trying to make some kind of CMS or reporting system in which the definition of what data to display can be altered through a user interface. There are gems for this kind of thing but seeing as you're on this track...

By :human_attribute_name I assume you mean the friendly name to be displayed on the page as a label. First of all it would be more appropriate to use a string rather than symbol as you can then use spaces and more characters. Assuming you never intend to have duplicate label names on the same webpage you could try using a hash instead of an array.

```
fields = { 
           "Field One" => "field_one" ,
           "Field Two" => "field_two" ,
           "Field One Of Some Association" => "some_association.field_one"
         }
```

and then fetch the data in a similar way to that shown in the answer you referenced.

```
data = {}

fields.each_pair do | friendly_name, attribute |
  data[friendly_name] = if attribute.include?('.')
    attribute.split('.').inject(some_object, :send)
  else
    some_object.send(attribute)
  end
end
```

That should leave you with a hash you can loop over in your view like this

```
{ 
  "Field One" => "Mr" ,
  "Field Two" => "Data",
  "Field One Of Some Association" => "A Friend Of Mr Data"
}
```